# how to override touch functions properly in iOS 9, swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, touch

Well, I says on the lines `changeColorTo(touch: touches.anyObject() as? UITouch)`

this error "value of type "Set" has no member "anyObject"

How can I fix the problem?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    changeColorTo(touch: touches.anyObject() as? UITouch)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    changeColorTo(touch: touches.anyObject() as? UITouch)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    changeColorTo(touch: touches.anyObject() as? UITouch)
}

func changeColorTo(touch  touch: UITouch? ) {
    if let contact = touch {
        changeColorTo(point: contact.locationInView(self))
    }
}

func changeColorTo(point  point: CGPoint ) {
    // Change the color model to the color displayed at the given view coordinate
    if let color = colorModel {
        let bounds = self.bounds
        if bounds.contains(point) {
            color.hue = Float((point.x-bounds.minX)/bounds.width*360)
            color.saturation = Float((point.y-bounds.minY)/bounds.height*100)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass UITouch set to CGPoint.

Try the below to solve the issues,

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInView(self)
        changeColorTo(location)
    }

    func changeColorTo(point: CGPoint ) {

    }
```